# CentOS 6.3 svn command line update

Tags: svn, centos

I am using centos 6.3.I had installed SVN server on same.I took checkout on same machine as well as on windows machine.

I made change in file on windows machine & did commit.It worked fine.But when i did update on centos's checkout location using

"sudo svn update http/111.111.111.111/svn/testrepo /var/www/vhosts/vps-zzz-rrr.manage.myhosting.com/httpdocs/sites/tsosdfsvn/"

I am getting below msg

Skipped 'http/111.111.111.111/svn/testrepo'
svn: OPTIONS of 'http/111.111.111.111/repos/tso': 200 OK (http/111.111.111.111)

& my changes not reflected at checkout location on centos.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

The 'svn update' command should only take one argument:

sudo svn update /var/www/vhosts/vps-zzz-rrr.manage.myhosting.com/httpdocs/sites/tsosdfsvn

Comment: Its showing me below msg.
svn: OPTIONS of 'Webpate': 200 OK 

But i am not able to see changes which i did in files